# How to resolve Intune iOS wrapping error "An invalid signing certificate was specified"

Tags: ios, swift, intune

I am developing iOS native application for which want to add Microsoft Intune support. While packaging the application I am getting error as:

```
Application packaging in progress...
Version of MACOSX is 10.15.7
Version of XCode installed is Xcode 12.4
Build version 12D4e

Parsing provisioning profile...
Parsing main app provisioning profile...
Parsing extension provisioning profiles...
Checking that main provisioning profile has not expired...
Checking that extension provisioning profiles have not expired...
Checking if signing certificate is valid...
Number of certificates returned by query: 12
Checking certificate at index: 0
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 1
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 2
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 3
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 4
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 5
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 6
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 7
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 8
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 9
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 10
Getting certificate common name.
Checking certificate at index: 11
Getting certificate common name.
An invalid signing certificate was specified. Specify a valid Apple signing certificate.
Cause of the error to be provided for investigation:(null)
```

I have crosscheck SHA1, certificate, profile, AdHoc ipa, etc 2-3 times. But still get "An invalid signing certificate was specified. Specify a valid Apple signing certificate."

I am using:

- Intune SDK version 14.4.1
- Xcode version: 12.4

I have tried with 2 different certificate. Screen shot of keychain certificate is
[image: Keychain certificate]

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the distribution certificate was working fine in xcode for creating .ipa file but showing "An invalid signing certificate was specified. Specify a valid Apple signing certificate." error while wrapping with intune command line tool.

It started working for me when I removed the double quotes and spaces from SHA1.

so instead of

```
-c "23 34 B5..."
```

do this:

```
-c 2334B5...
```

Second option is to use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
-c '23 34 B5...'
```

or

```
-c 'Name of Certificate in keychain'
```

I hope this will help someone.

Thanks